# What does double brace mean in template code, after c++11?

Tags: c++, function, templates, return, c++17

I saw some valid template code as below:

```
template<typename R, typename P, size_t N, size_t... I>
constexpr array<R, N> to_array_impl(P (&a)[N], std::index_sequence<I...>) noexcept
{
    return { {a[I]...} };
}
```

Well, what does the double brace mean here? When do we need to use double brace(I'm using c++17 now), I guess it's restricted to `return` statement?

I also see code like below, that there's function call inside double braces:

```
template<typename R, typename P, size_t N, size_t... I>
constexpr array<R, N> to_array_impl(P (&&a)[N], std::index_sequence<I...>) noexcept
{
    return { {move(a[I])...} };
}
```

So what's the difference here between using one brace and two braces?

Thanks!

Comment: It's an initializer, like `std::array<int,3> a {{1,2,3}};`

Comment: You don't need double braces in your example. Also, you tagged C++11, but `index_sequence` is only valid since C++14.

Answer (score 1):

> When do we need to use double brace(I'm using c++17 now), I guess it's restricted to return statement?

The double braces are not require in your given example. Just surrounding the pack expansion with one set of braces is enough.

> So what's the difference here between using one brace and two braces?

In your given example, adding double braces have no additional effect.  That is, using single set of braces is equivalent to using double braces(in the given example).